# reading JSON file in apex

Tags: apex, json

I'm trying to extract the values from JSON, what is the simple and easy way to do and I have tried few different way but none of the approach works, I looked [json2apex](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) but that approach never worked.

Here is the error I'm getting for the below code, how should I deal with this error? and I don't control how the JSON output renders.

> Error: Line: 11, Column: 1 System.JSONException: Illegal unquoted
> character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): has to be escaped using backslash to
> be included in string value at [line:1, column:586]
>
> Line: 11, Column: 1 System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('V'
> (code 86)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries at [line:1,
> column:615]

APEX Code:

```
 String sessionId = fetchUserSessionId();
    HTTP h = new HTTP();
    HTTPRequest req = new HTTPRequest();
    HttpResponse resp = new HttpResponse();
    req.setMethod('GET');
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + sessionId);
    req.setEndpoint(getHostURL() + endpoint);
    resp = h.send(req); 
    String jsonStr = resp.getBody();   

 
String ParserOutput= jsonStr.replaceAll('\n','').replaceAll('\r','');
//String transformedText = ParserOutput.replace('""', '"'); 
String responseText = ParserOutput.trim().replace('\uFEFF', '');
// Parse entire JSON response.

//deserializeUntyped works
Map<String, Object> jsonMap = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(responseText);
```

JSON

```
{
  "size": 1,
  "totalSize": 1,
  "done": true,
  "queryLocator": null,
  "entityTypeName": "CustomField",
  "records": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "CustomField",
        "url": "/services/data/v46.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/00N6g00000TAlZNEA1"
      },
      "Metadata1": {
        "businessOwnerGroup": null,
        "businessOwnerUser": null,
        "formula": "IMAGE( \nCASE(Rating__c, \n\"Very Bad\", \"/img/samples/stars_100.gif\",\n\"Bad\", \"/img/samples/stars_200.gif\",\n\"Okay\", \"/img/samples/stars_300.gif\", \n\"Good\", \"/img/samples/stars_400.gif\", \n\"Very Good\", \"/img/samples/stars_500.gif\", \n\"/img/samples/stars_000.gif\"), \n\"rating\")",
        "formulaTreatBlanksAs": "BlankAsZero"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: which is the endpoint you are hitting in salesforce ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate more, one way to actually apply and store the changes to `jsonMap`, we could do the following.

```
if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
  // Deserialize the JSON string into collections of primitive data types.
  Map<String, Object> jsonMap = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());

  // Iterate over the keys in the map
  for (String key : jsonMap.keySet()) {
    Object value = jsonMap.get(key);
    if(value != null){
      value = String.valueOf(value).replaceAll('\n','').replaceAll('\r','').replace('\uFEFF', '');
    }
    jsonMap.put(key, value);
  }

  System.debug(jsonMap);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your main issue is here:

```
String ParserOutput= jsonStr.replaceAll('\n','').replaceAll('\r','');
```

In Apex code, `\` is an escape character, so you're actually trying to remove the CR+LF bytes from the code, which is not the same as removing the literal `\n` in the string. To do that, you'd need to double up on the escape sequences. In addition, the replaceAll function is using a regular expression, so the `\` itself must be escaped again:

```
String ParserOutput= jsonStr.replaceAll('\\\\n','').replaceAll('\\\\r','');
```

However, this is apparently pointless. I actually just copy-pasted your response JSON into a Static Resource, and parsed it directly in Apex, without modification, and it parsed just fine. I don't think you need to do all the extra work you're doing at that phase in the code.

```
StaticResource s = [select body from staticresource where name = 'q308772'];
System.debug(
    json.deserializeuntyped(s.body.tostring())
);
```

Comment: How do I extract values from `ParserOutput`  like attributes, type, url...

Comment: See the other answer, but you start with a `Map<String, Object> values = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(parserOutput)`, then you can: `values.get('size')`, etc. For nested objects, they will be `Map<String, Object>` as well, and you can read those elements the same way.

Comment: I tried to do `Map<String, Object> values = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(parserOutput)` and I get the size by doing `values.get('size')` but when I try to read the value for the `url` I tried something like this  `Map<String, Object> values2 = (Map<String, Object>)values.get('records')` then I get this error `system.typeexception: invalid conversion from runtime type LIST<ANY> TO mAP<STRING, ANY>`

Comment: @NickKahn It's a `List<Object>`, which you then cast each element in to a `Map<String, Object>`.